# How to add user interface design in microservice architecture

Tags: vue.js, user-interface, microservices

I'm building small `vue.js` microservice application and I have few doubts. Firstly I'm using `mongoDB` as my database, and I'm using `express`. After I want to use `Docker` and `Kubernetes` to deploy the application.
I want to use 5 microservices:

1. Basic publishing and product catalog
2. Commenting inside the post
3. Products can be added to cart
4. Paying the certain products after the cart
5. User authentification (login and register)

So the problem is how to add user interface design if the microservices which I want to use are backend based. How to exactly add the frontend if it can't be part of microservices. Or maybe should I use `React` and implement `HTML/CSS` things inside `javascript` code? Is it even possible because I want to use just `MongoDB` for every database needed in a microservice and write every microservice in `Vue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always upto you what you are good and requirement.

There is no specific best practice with microservices to follow certain languages together, people use the different languages in microservice like Ruby, Node, with React as front or one Python service managing the user auth.

It's depends on you what you are good with and familiar with.

You can create the Python app as a user interface or react or HTML which call backend services over **API** calls or **grpc**.

There is one example in the **Istio** repo : https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/samples/bookinfo

It's a book info app in Node, Ruby, Python using databases like MySQL, MongoDB etc.

https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/deploy-bookinfo

**Update** :

For Vue base, this blog and repo might be helpful **vue-microfrontend**

https://itnext.io/setup-a-micro-frontend-architecture-with-vue-and-single-spa-2c89528bf72f

Repo : https://github.com/vue-microfrontends

Comment: This is just what I wanted! Can you give me the exact example of HTML which call backends services over API calls.. I just want to use Node (vue.js) for now because I'm most familiar with it.

Comment: https://github.com/vue-microfrontends & https://itnext.io/setup-a-micro-frontend-architecture-with-vue-and-single-spa-2c89528bf72f..udpated in answer also.

Comment: Can you send the correct link? it says Error 404 not found

Comment: check in answer also i have updated answer. also updated in a comment now.